# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli'

Tags: python, linux, pip

Need some help here.

I have two versions of `pip` and `pip3` installed in different location.

When I try to do a `pip install package-name` it throws Error as:

```
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli'
```

````
pip 18.1 from /project/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
$ which pip
/project/miniconda/bin/pip
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
$ pip -V
pip 18.1 from /project/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
$ pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli'```
````

Since I don't have super user access, I cannot modify pip._internal.cli.main to pip.internal.cli.main.

Please help.

Comment: ``python3 -m pip install package-name`` works?

Comment: im having the same issue on my macbook:
pip3
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module> from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please upgrade pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`.

You can try to install any package with: `python -m pip install package-name` for python2.7 and `python3 -m pip install package-name` for python3.

Using python -m pip install instead of just pip install is recommended. The reason is that it will use the correct interpreter for your python installation, specially if you have many versions installed. More details here: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: Worked for me too ty :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this it worked for me

`python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip`

[Image Link for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLfSg.png)