# PIP install py package

Tags: python

I have tried searching GitHub and updating my PIP version. However, it's still an error.
my input:

```
pip install web3[tester]
```

my output:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\yeeha\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yeeha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4i7hnz9q\\pyethash_ae54d7cacb0a40b2b448b8e6651ec678\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yeeha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4i7hnz9q\\pyethash_ae54d7cacb0a40b2b448b8e6651ec678\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\yeeha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-epq1ifn9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\yeeha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\pyethash'
         cwd: C:\Users\yeeha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4i7hnz9q\pyethash_ae54d7cacb0a40b2b448b8e6651ec678\
    Complete output (65 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyethash' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\python
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\libethash
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/python/core.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/python/core.obj -Isrc/ -std=gnu99 -Wall
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu99'
    core.c
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\object.h(182): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'slot'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\object.h(190): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'flags'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/object.h(212): warning C4820: '_typeobject': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'tp_flags'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/object.h(256): warning C4820: '_typeobject': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'tp_version_tag'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\pytime.h(123): warning C4115: 'timeval': named type definition in parentheses
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\bytearrayobject.h(30): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'ob_exports'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\bytesobject.h(41): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'ob_sval'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\bytesobject.h(165): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'small_buffer'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(221): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'state'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/unicodeobject.h(625): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '2' bytes padding added after data member 'readonly'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\longintrepr.h(88): warning C4820: '_longobject': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'ob_digit'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\memoryobject.h(45): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'flags'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\memoryobject.h(62): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'flags'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\methodobject.h(56): warning C4820: 'PyMethodDef': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'ml_flags'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\moduleobject.h(63): warning C4820: 'PyModuleDef_Slot': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'slot'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/initconfig.h(16): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_type'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/initconfig.h(19): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'exitcode'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/initconfig.h(202): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'parse_argv'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/initconfig.h(357): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'legacy_windows_stdio'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/initconfig.h(367): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'pathconfig_warnings'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/initconfig.h(374): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'module_search_paths_set'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/initconfig.h(393): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'skip_source_first_line'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pystate.h(65): warning C4820: '_ts': '2' bytes padding added after data member 'recursion_critical'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pystate.h(73): warning C4820: '_ts': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'use_tracing'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pystate.h(96): warning C4820: '_ts': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'gilstate_counter'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pystate.h(130): warning C4820: '_ts': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'coroutine_origin_tracking_depth'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\genobject.h(35): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'gi_running'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\genobject.h(55): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'cr_running'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\genobject.h(72): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'ag_running'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\genobject.h(85): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'ag_running_async'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\descrobject.h(29): warning C4820: 'wrapperbase': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'offset'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\descrobject.h(33): warning C4820: 'wrapperbase': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'flags'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\structseq.h(20): warning C4820: 'PyStructSequence_Desc': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'n_in_sequence'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(19): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'suppress_context'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(23): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'suppress_context'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(33): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'suppress_context'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(40): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'suppress_context'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(49): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'suppress_context'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(54): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'suppress_context'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\cpython/pyerrors.h(66): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '7' bytes padding added after data member 'suppress_context'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\modsupport.h(97): warning C4820: '_PyArg_Parser': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'max'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\code.h(32): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'co_firstlineno'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\code.h(69): warning C4820: '<unnamed-tag>': '3' bytes padding added after data member 'co_opcache_size'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\import.h(138): warning C4820: '_frozen': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'size'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\fileutils.h(73): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'st_dev'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\fileutils.h(75): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '2' bytes padding added after data member 'st_mode'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\fileutils.h(79): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'st_rdev'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\fileutils.h(82): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'st_atime_nsec'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\fileutils.h(84): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'st_mtime_nsec'
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include\fileutils.h(88): warning C4820: '_Py_stat_struct': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'st_reparse_tag'
    src/python/core.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'alloca.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\yeeha\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\yeeha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4i7hnz9q\\pyethash_ae54d7cacb0a40b2b448b8e6651ec678\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\yeeha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4i7hnz9q\\pyethash_ae54d7cacb0a40b2b448b8e6651ec678\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\yeeha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-epq1ifn9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\yeeha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Include\pyethash' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please try following the instructions I gave in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67397045/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pip-internal-cli/67399694#67399694

Comment: For reference, the actual error in all of that output is: `src/python/core.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'alloca.h': No such file or directory`.  This